# Was the Blood from Gara's Sand Coffin always black?

Tags: naruto

in Episode 34, "Akamaru Trembles: Gaara's Cruel Strength!", when Gara goes to use his Sand Coffin Justu the blood that explodes out is shown to be black

[image: Sand Coffin]
[image: Raining Blood]
[image: Raining Blood 2]

when i first saw this i figured this is a censored episode as some versions of Naruto censor out the blood (ie. coughing up blood ends up being coughing up saliva). but then in Episode 50, "The Fifth Gate: A Splendid Ninja is Born" when Gara goes to use Sand Coffin on Lee's Arm and Leg, Shikamaru recognises the Jutsu and we see a flash back of Gara using Sand Coffin in the Forest of Death (a repeat of the scene from the 1st screenshot), but when Lee's will make him get up to continue fighting, we see his arm and leg covered in blood

[image: Lee's Arm and Leg]

so was blood from Gara's Sand Coffin always black in the anime? as in any version of the anime, subbed, dubbed, 4kids, original japanese version. if it was always meant to be black (and not censored) why is the blood black?

Comment: Not an answer, I believe it was always black; although I can't say for certain. The only discussion I've found regarding this is on this [IGN](https://www.ignboards.com/threads/no-blood.149017389/) discussion board. A user mentioned it was red in the original Japanese release, but no source to back it up.

Comment: Regardless, the black blood can be explained by quoting Gaara in the English dubbed episode he initially used the justu - "[...] I crushed him with more force than necessary [...] The corpse's bitter crimson tears flow and mingle in the endless sand'. So the black blood came from the blood and sand being mixed together. While lee's arms and legs were crushed in the same manner, they continued to bleed blood that wasn't mixed with the same

Comment: 2 theories I can come up with: 1. Naruto is a children show at that time , so showing blood and guts spilling in its actual color could have been traumatizing. So, they made the color black and omitted any bones and guts. (OR) 2. Gaara used so much strength that the sand got infused into the blood making it dirtier.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify, the stuff coming out of Gaara's Sand Burial is not blood, but rather Flesh-Bone-and-Skin puree. This stuff is normally red (yes, it's almost always red) but because "he used more force than necessary" the flesh puree became black. To answer your question, this is intentional, and is not a form of censoring.

Against Rock Lee, because Rock Lee's body was receding from the effects of a few of the 8 gates (I guess) His bones were fractured by his muscles were spared of being liquified (because of the gates). The stuff coming out then was just blood.

In Shippuden, a similar thing happens with Deidara Losing an arm. Because Deidara cannot open the 8 gates, his arm was destroyed. Apparently, Gaara wasn't using a lot of force, because the flesh puree was red at that time.

[image: Deidara's arm getting crushed by Gaara]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the blood was always black, so inside your red blood cells there is oxygen, so when the blood cells die they release oxygen and the oxygen makes that blood a dark red that looks black.

Comment: Huh? My blood becomes dark red(==black) when blood cells die??